# How to trigger OnClick and OnClientClick events simultaneously in ASP.NET when using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to display a message bar during postback. I am using a jQuery script I found online [here](http://www.andreyvoev.com/programming/jquery-plugin-messagebar/). Everything works great separately, but when the jQuery is added to the page my server side event is never called.

Here is my button code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGetReport" CssClass="float-left" runat="server" 
Text="<%$ Glossary:GetReport %>" OnClick="btnGetReport_Click" />
```

This is the inline script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=btnGetReport.ClientID%>').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#message_bar').displayMessage({
            position: 'fixed',
            skin: 'modern',
            message: 'We are fetching your report. Please wait...',
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the related external .js file:

```
(function( $ ){

$.fn.displayMessage = function(options) {

    // Default configuration properties.
     var defaults = {
              message       : 'Error message',
              speed         : 'fast',
              position      : 'fixed', // relative, absolute, fixed
              autohide      : true
     }

    var options = $.extend( defaults, options );
    $(this).slideUp('fast');
    $(this).removeClass().empty();
    return this.each(function() {

      var sticky = (options.sticky == false) ? 'relative' : 'absolute';
      $(this).addClass('messagebar-skin-'+options.skin+'_bar').css('position',options.position).css('background-color',options.background);
      $(this).append('<div class="messagebar-skin-'+options.skin+'_inner"><span class="messagebar-skin-'+options.skin+'_text"></span></div>').css('color',options.color);
      $(this).find('span').html(options.message);

      $(this).slideDown(options.speed ,function(){

         var parent = ($(this).attr('id')) ? "#"+$(this).attr('id') : "."+$(this).attr('class');
         var close_button = ($(this).find('a').attr('id')) ? "#"+$(this).find('a').attr('id') : "."+$(this).find('a').attr('class');

         if(options.autohide == true)
         {
            $(this).delay(2400).fadeOut('slow');
         }

         $(parent+">div>"+close_button).bind("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(parent+">div>"+close_button).animate({"opacity": "hide"}, function(){
                $(parent+">div>span").fadeOut("slow").html("");
                $(parent+">div>"+close_button).parent().parent().slideUp(options.speed);
            });
         });

  });

});

};
})( jQuery );
```

I have also tried calling the function with the OnClientClick property, but neither one seems to work. I looked at other examples where people were having issues with this but none of them seemed to help either.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried something simple like:

```
OnClientClick="return YourJavaScriptFunction();"

<asp:Button ID="btnGetReport" CssClass="float-left" runat="server" 
    Text="<%$ Glossary:GetReport %>" OnClick="btnGetReport_Click" 
    OnClientClick="return YourJavaScriptFunction();" />
```

and in your JavaScript function return `true` at the end

```
function YourJavaScriptFunction () {
    // your cool stuff
    return true;
}
```

### Edit 1

This line:

```
OnClientClick="return YourJavaScriptFunction();"
```

It's the equivalent to:

```
$('#<%=btnGetReport.ClientID%>').click(function () {
```

Your script would look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function YourJavaScriptFunction (){
        $('#message_bar').displayMessage({
            position: 'fixed',
            skin: 'modern',
            message: 'We are fetching your report. Please wait...'
        });    

        // this will prevent the postback, equivalent to: event.preventDefault();
        return false;
}

</script>
```

Comment: I don't have much experience with jQuery so I'm not entirely sure how to do that. How do I make the function call and bypass "$('#<%=btnGetReport.ClientID%>').click(function (event)" in the inline script?

Comment: I placed my button into an panel control and added the DefaultButton property to allow the user to press enter. The jQuery function fires, but once again the server side is not. It works fine if I click on it, just not when pressing enter. Any thoughts?

Comment: I was able to solve the issue in case anyone has a similar problem. My original OnClientClick property on the DefaultButton was OnClientClick="return testClick();". I changed it to  OnClientClick="if(!testClick()){return true;}" and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=btnGetReport.ClientID%>').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#message_bar').displayMessage({
                position: 'fixed',
                skin: 'modern',
                message: 'We are fetching your report. Please wait...',
            });
         __doPostBack("btnGetReport", "");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

if using Master Page then try this:

```
 __doPostBack("ctl00$MainContent$btnGetReport", "");
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. The postback occurred but the client side and server side functions did not fire. Thank you for your help however.